# Как выполнить сортировку в основе значения поля

Tags: сортировка, mongodb, aggregation-framework

У меня возникла проблема с сортировкой. Мне нужно отсортировать по полям `f0`, `f1`, `f2`, но при этом не учитывать регистр символа, а записи у которых нет поля - поместить в конец списка.

Вот тестовые данные:

```
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "A", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "A", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "A", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "A", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "a", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "a", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "a", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "a", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "B", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "B", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "B", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "B", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "b", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "b", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "b", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "b", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A", f1: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "A", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "A", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "A", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "A", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "a", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "a", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "a", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "a", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "B", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "B", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "B", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "B", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "b", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "b", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "b", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "b", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a", f1: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "A", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "A", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "A", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "A", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "a", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "a", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "a", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "a", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "B", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "B", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "B", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "B", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "b", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "b", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "b", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "b", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B", f1: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "A", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "A", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "A", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "A", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "a", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "a", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "a", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "a", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "B", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "B", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "B", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "B", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "b", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "b", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "b", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "b", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b", f1: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({f0: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "A", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "A", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "A", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "A", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "a", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "a", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "a", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "a", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "B", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "B", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "B", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "B", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "b", f2: "A"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "b", f2: "a"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "b", f2: "B"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "b", f2: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({ f1: "b"});
db.getCollection("test").insert({});
```

Вот сам запрос:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({}).sort({"f0": 1,"f1": 1,"f2": 1});
```

А вот вывод, и в нем видно, что пустые значения он вытаскивает наверх, потом идут заглавные буквы, а потом маленькие. Мне нужно, сначала буква `a|A`, `b|B` и уже потом пустые значения.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d737")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d727"),
    "f1" : "A"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d723"),
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d725"),
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d724"),
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d726"),
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d731"),
    "f1" : "B"
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72d"),
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72f"),
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72e"),
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d730"),
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72c"),
    "f1" : "a"
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d728"),
    "f1" : "a",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72a"),
    "f1" : "a",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 15 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d729"),
    "f1" : "a",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 16 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d72b"),
    "f1" : "a",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 17 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d736"),
    "f1" : "b"
}

/* 18 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d732"),
    "f1" : "b",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 19 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d734"),
    "f1" : "b",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 20 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d733"),
    "f1" : "b",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 21 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d735"),
    "f1" : "b",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 22 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6e3"),
    "f0" : "A"
}

/* 23 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d3"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "A"
}

/* 24 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6cf"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 25 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d1"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 26 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d0"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 27 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d2"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "A",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 28 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6dd"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "B"
}

/* 29 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d9"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "A"
}

/* 30 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6db"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "B"
}

/* 31 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6da"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "a"
}

/* 32 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6dc"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "B",
    "f2" : "b"
}

/* 33 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d88d97b9999b45267d6d8"),
    "f0" : "A",
    "f1" : "a"
}
```

Comment: Варианты с сортировкой _после_ извлечения данных вы не рассматриваете? Почему?

Comment: Это не подходит, так как документов может быть большое количество. И хотелось бы использовать индекс базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

Индексы в MongoDB пока что не могут быть case insensitive. Вот feature request со статусом "open":

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Если вам не критично оптимальное использование индексов, можно решить поставленную задачу при помощи [**Aggregation Framework**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/):

## Решение

```js
db.test.aggregate(
{
    "$project":
    {
        f0: 1,
        f1: 1,
        f2: 1,
        f0_sortable:
        {
            $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$f0", null ] }, then: { "$toLower": "$f0" }, else: [] }
        },
        f1_sortable:
        {
            $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$f1", null ] }, then: { "$toLower": "$f1" }, else: [] }
        },
        f2_sortable:
        {
            $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$f2", null ] }, then: { "$toLower": "$f2" }, else: [] }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort":
    {
        f0_sortable: 1,
        f1_sortable: 1,
        f2_sortable: 1,
        f0: 1,
        f1: 1,
        f2: 1
    }
},
{
    "$project":
    {
        f0: 1,
        f1: 1,
        f2: 1
    }
})
```

## Пояснение

#### 1. Первый [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

На этом шаге мы для каждого объекта выбираем изначальные поля (`f0`, `f1`, `f2`) и создаём новые поля (`*_sortable`), которые будут использоваться только для сортировки. Например:

```
$cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$f2", null ] }, then: { "$toLower": "$f2" }, else: [] }
```

Это выражение вернёт значение поля `f2` в нижнем регистре если в объекте есть ненулевое поле `f2`. В противном случае, вернётся `[]` — т.е. массив. Я так сделал потому, что массивы всегда считаются в порядке сортировки больше чем, строки.

#### 2. [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

Сортируем сначала по нашим `*_sortable` полям, а затем ещё и по изначальным полям, для красоты (`A, a, a` будет идти раньше, чем `a, A, A`).

#### 3. Второй [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Оставляем в результатах только изначальные поля `f0`, `f1`, `f2`.